# WARN 86540 --- [-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1

Tags: docker-compose

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh1pP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1nWz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUzG5.png)

Hello! Help to fix the problem when launching the application, the warning is added and nothing works on photo 2 of the config file : docker-compose.yaml and application.properties

I'm launching the route, the web interface should be available.Named ports.Nothing changes.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and check your tags - especially their descriptions. I've removed the irrelevant [tag:apache].